# why the "In-comming email settings" is missing under the "Library settings >>Communication"

Tags: list, installation, configuration, farm, smtp

I am working on SharePoint 2013 , and i want to configure in-coming email to my custom list. so i went to "library setting >> communication section" but i can not find any link to configure the In-comming email , as follow:-

[image]

now i have installed the SMTP service on my SharePoint server and i have start it as follow:-

[image]

[image]

i also did a iis reset but can not see the link inside the custom list settings, also i try accessing the list setting for an announcement list and it is missing the link ...

Comment: Yes, custom list don't have he incoming email feature, document library having the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only certain lists support incoming email, like discussion boards and calendar. Custom list is not one of them.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-and-configure-e-mail-support-for-a-list-or-library-DCAF44A0-1D9B-451A-84C7-6C52E7DB908E